# Difference between using a categorical variable vs separate dummy variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have 2 drug treatment groups, namely Cis and RT. So, a cell is either exposed to none, Cis only, RT only, or a combination of Cis+RT. There is also another cancer modality group.

I would like to perform a linear model, but I am not sure if I should use a categorical variable with 4 groups or 2 dummy variables for the drug treatment.

**Option 1** (`tx_group`) with categories:

1. NT
2. Cis
3. RT
4. Cis+RT

or **Option 2** (`cis` and `rt`):

1. 0
2. 1

Based on the above, considering an interaction model, the formula would be either
`y ~ tx_group*cancer_group` or `y~cis*rt*cancer_group`. Which one should I use?

Comment: The variance explained by the two options will be exactly the same. It comes down to preference, ease of interpretation, and which more directly reflects your test of interest. My own preference would be option 2. Is there a specific comparison that you're most interested in?